# Powershell - check if three variables match two specific strings

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I have to check if the variables $var1, $var2, $var3 contain "172.20.110." or "172.20.111.". Is there a way to this with an IF statement (not a beautiful solution) or is there a better way to that. For Example: Can I create a "network object" with 172.20.110.0/23 (255.255.254) and check the variables against it?

Comment: We will be able to help you if you clarify your question. e. g. provide examples what `$var1` looks like; what you wan't to compare with what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to use `-match` to find "172.20.110" in $var1. The `-match` operator returns a bool that you can check. You can figure out the if statements to compare them how you need. Check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) for more on comparison operators that you might rather use.

```
$var1 = "somestuff172.20.110morestuff"
if($var1 -match "172.20.110"){"was true"}
else{"was false"}
```